# How to Insert bulk Array of data in mssql table using nodejs

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server, express

I am using node-mssql, LInk : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

i want to insert bulk array of data in mssql database

i am getting array of array records  eg: [[row1],[row2],[row3]]

i want to insert these records in mssql database

```
import * as sql from "mssql";

const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool({
   user: "XXXXXXXXX",
   password: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
   server: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
   database: "TESTDATA",
   options: {
    instanceName: "XXX"
   },
   pool: {
     max: 10,
     min: 0,
     idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
   }
 });

conn.connect()

var values = [[john,1,4,80],[jenny,2,4,78],[abhi,3,4.60],[ram,4,4,90]]

new sql.Request(conn)
    .query(`INSERT INTO CLASS_TABLE (NAME, ROLL, CLASS, MARKS) VALUES
 ${values.map(row=>{ var num = Array('(' + row.join() + ')' ).join(); return num })}`)
```

Error : The label '@' has already been declared. Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [bulk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#bulk-table-options-callback)

```
const table = new sql.Table('CLASS_TABLE');
table.columns.add('NAME', sql.NVarChar(15), {nullable: false});
table.columns.add('ROLL', sql.Int, {nullable: false});
table.columns.add('CLASS', sql.Int, {nullable: false});
table.columns.add('MARKS', sql.Int, {nullable: false});

values.forEach(arr => table.rows.add.apply(null, arr));

const request = new sql.Request();
request.bulk(table, (err, result) => {
  // ... error checks
});
```

Comment: ERROR: Cannot read property 'push' of null", 
I am getting this Error
if array is this
   [[john,1,4,80],[jenny,2,null,78],[abhi,3,4.60],[ram,4,4,null]]

Comment: @SaiJeevanBalla the example you gave all had values, if some columns can be null then you can just adjust `{nullable: false}` to `{nullable: true}` for those ones.

Comment: can you help me out of this ERROR: RequestError: Connection lost - read ECONNRESET, while inserting bulk data in mssql table it will lost the connection

Comment: What if you want to insert into an existing table and don't want to specify the column type for each column? I.e. when you are devloping a generic framework, with table names and columns not known upfront?

Comment: @Ya. for this particular library, [you must to define the column type](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/blob/777b1a2a440241117a3a7b742f17ee7156fb4e3f/lib/table.js#L26). And, to be honest, I don't think you'll find many frameworks that won't at least require the consumer to provide the column type in some manner e.g. perhaps even just by inspecting the data type being passed? e.g. if it's a string value, assume `NVarChar(len)`, if int assume `Int`, if float presume `Float` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Better answer:

```
import {
  ConnectionPool,
  Table,
  VarChar,
  Int,
} from 'mssql';

var values = [[john,1,4,80],[jenny,2,4,78],[abhi,3,4,60],[ram,4,4,90]];

const table = new Table('CLASS_TABLE');
table.create = false;
// Ignore the identity field
table.columns.add('NAME', VarChar, { nullable: true });
table.columns.add('ROLL', Int, { nullable: true });
table.columns.add('CLASS', Int, { nullable: true });
table.columns.add('MARKS', Int, { nullable: true });

for (let j = 0; j < values.length; j += 1) {
  table.rows.add(
    values[j][0],
    values[j][1],
    values[j][2],
    values[j][3]
  );
}
const request = pool.request();

const results = await request.bulk(table);
console.log(`rows affected ${results.rowsAffected}`);
```

Comment: Can you write a bit about what's happening in this code that makes it superior to the other answer?

Comment: yes, the other examples did not work. the main enhancement is table.rows.add(
    values[j][0],
    values[j][1],
    values[j][2],
    values[j][3]
  );

Answer (score 0):

Update to Williams answer:

```
import {
ConnectionPool,
Table,
VarChar,
Int,
} from 'mssql';
let values = [[john,1,4,80],[jenny,2,4,78],[abhi,3,4,60],[ram,4,4,90]];
const table = new Table('CLASS_TABLE');
table.create = false;
// Ignore the identity field
table.columns.add('NAME', VarChar, { nullable: true });
table.columns.add('ROLL', Int, { nullable: true });
table.columns.add('CLASS', Int, { nullable: true });
table.columns.add('MARKS', Int, { nullable: true });
//If you have an array of arrays you can map it without hard coding the amount of values needed
//for (let j = 0; j < values.length; j += 1) {
// table.rows.add(
//    values[j][0],
//    values[j][1],
//    values[j][2],
//    values[j][3]
//  );
//}

//Updated way allows for dynamically added columns coming from something like a config file
values.forEach(row => table.rows.add.apply(table.rows,row));
const request = pool.request();
const results = await request.bulk(table);
console.log(`rows affected ${results.rowsAffected}`);
```