# Azure SQL Edge streaming reading from JSON

Tags: node.js, azure-sql-database, azure-iot-edge, azure-data-studio, azure-sql-edge

I'm trying to place JSON in a table where each key would be a value in a column, and I receive these two types of errors:

1. 09/27/2023 16:41:00,
   "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/SUBSCRIPTIONID/RESOURCEGROUPS/RESOURCEGROUP/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.STREAMANALYTICS/STREAMINGJOBS/MUVUDB.MONITORINGVARIABLESDATA",
   "Send Events", "Execution", "InProgress", "Warning",
   "{"Source":"MonitoringVariablesOutput","Type":"DataError","DataErrorType":"OutputDataConversionError.TypeConversionError","BriefMessage":null,"ErrorCode":"DatabaseOutputTypeConversionError","ErrorCategory":"DataError","Message":"Cannot
   convert from property 'valueDec' of type 'System.String' to column
   'valueDec' of type
   'System.Double'.","ExampleEvents":"[\"{\\"monitoringVariableId\\":\\"test\\",\\"readTime\\":\\"test2\\",\\"aggregationVariable\\":\\"test3\\",\\"valueStr\\":\\"test4\\"}\"]","FromTimestamp":"2023-09-27T16:41:00.5952370Z","ToTimestamp":"2023-09-27T16:41:00.5953991Z","EventCount":1}"]
2. The value of the key valueDec (float) is stored in valueStr (nvarchar), even if the keys are diferent in JSON.

The azuredatastudio configuration and edge module code were working in the past in other devices.

My edge module has the following code to in NodeJS to send the json:

```
var body = {
          monitoringVariableId: "test",
          readTime: "test2",
          aggregationVariable: "test3",
          valueDec: 4
        }
var message = JSON.stringify(body)
var outputMsg = new Message(message);
client.sendOutputEvent("output1", outputMsg);
```

Don't know if it is a newer version of Azure SQL Edge, this never happenend to me... It seems that azureSQLEdge is not doing the parse in my message and every value is String.

Comment: @PauloIIheu could please share the reference/DOC/git you used to connect to `Azuresqledge`

Comment: Are you trying to send a JSON message to the `Azure-SQL-Edge` module in `Azure-Iot-Edge`

Answer (score 0):

- Create  a Azure IoT Hub and IOT edge.

[image]

[image]

- Create a [module](https://i.imgur.com/WJfB3sT.png) by adding AzureSQLEdge in IoT Edge Modules
  [image]
- Deploy Azure SQL [Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/deploy-portal)
- Connect and query Azure SQL [Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/connect#connect-to-azure-sql-edge-from-another-container-on-the-same-host) with nodejs refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56699317/how-to-insert-bulk-array-of-data-in-mssql-table-using-nodejs#:%7E:text=const%20table%20%3D%20new%20sql.Table%20%28%27CLASS_TABLE%27%29%3B%20table.columns.add%20%28%27NAME%27%2C,%28err%2C%20result%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%2F%2F...%20error%20checks%20%7D%29%3B).
- Sync data from Azure SQL Edge by using Azure Data [Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/tutorial-sync-data-factory)
- Build Graph Node and Edge Tables using Azure Data [Studio](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7375/build-graph-node-edge-tables-azure-data-studio/#:%7E:text=Launch%20the%20table%20designer%20and%20perform%20the%20following,the%20changes%20to%20deploy%20the%20new%20edge%20table.).